# Angular - How to represent JSON Login Response in Angular interface

Tags: angular

In Angular-13, after a user successfully logs in, I have this login response:

```
{
"data": {
    "id": "3333-3841-43d1-9bae-dddd",
    "token": "anythingsdsdsdsds",
    "user": {
        "id": 33333-3841-43d1-9bae-ea32e1165021",
        "firstName": "Janet",
        "lastName": "Wilow",
        "email": "janet@email.com",
        "userName": "JWilow"
      },
    "roles": [
        "Teacher"
     ],
    "expires": "2022-06-23T15:01:21.4727432+01:00",
    "refreshToken": "9333333-e67e-4deb-84a6-6efdraw"
},
"successful": true,
"message": "Login Successfully",
"statusCode": 200
}
```

Then in Angular, I want to create a LoginResponse Interface:

login-response.ts:

```
export interface LoginResponse{
}
```

How do I represent each field in the LoginResponse Interface?

Thanks

Comment: Use a converter [like this one](http://json2ts.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use multiple interfaces to represent each object.

```
export interface ILoginResponse{
data: ILoginDetails
successful: boolean;
message: string;
statusCode: boolean;
}

export interface ILogin{
 id: string;
 token: string;
 user: IUser;
 roles: IRole[];
 expires: Date;
 refreshToken: string;
}
export interface IUser{
 id: string;
 firstName: string;
 lastName: string;
 email: string;
 userName: string;
}
export interface IRole {
 role: string;
}
```